# How to increase the height of Label in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell , and I am loading from xib , so now as text may be dynamic so I want the height of UILabel present in Custom UITableViewCell dynamic ,

code of custom UITableViewCell is

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface NarrativeCell : UITableViewCell
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *noteTitle;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *noteDate;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *noteDesc;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *sideImage;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *imageButton;
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *audioStartButton; 
   @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *audioStopButton;

   @end
```

here is code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NarrativeCell";


    NarrativeCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil){
    NSLog(@"New Cell Made");

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NarrativeCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NarrativeCell class]])
        {
            cell = (NarrativeCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
Narratives *n=(Narratives *)[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGRect newFrame = cell.noteDesc.frame;


NSLog(@"old %f",newFrame.size.height);
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
//yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
NSLog(@"new %f",newFrame.size.height);
 newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;

[cell.noteDesc setFrame:newFrame];
[cell.noteDesc setNumberOfLines:0];

[cell.noteDesc setText:n.cfcnl_note];

return cell;

}
```

but unfortunately i can not resize the height of

```
             [cell.noteDesc setFrame:newFrame];
```

I think because it's loading from nib file , please help that how can I dynamically change the height of UILabel present custom UITableViewCell(created in nib).

/////////edit

see  the output of old new here
                  old 21.000000
                  new 42.000000

Comment: Do you get correct height for cell? Isn't it that noteDesc is resized with new frame but cell has smaller frame so noteDesc doesn't show completely?

Comment: What you have seems fine. Try doing cell.noteDesc.frame = CGMake(0,0,50,50); cell.noteDesc.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; or something to see if it's changing it when set explicitly. This will rule out a bad passing size.

Comment: @TravisM. its not effecting any more

Comment: i think i am loading from nib that may be the issue?

Comment: I don't think that should matter. I load all of my custom table cells from nibs and I can change their properties. Are you sure you have your UILabel connected to your noteDesc property in your subclass?

Comment: Does the setText command work properly? Also, if you have Use Autolayout checked on your nib it can cause some wacky stuff when you try to resize. Try turning it off if it's currently on and you're not using it.

Comment: yes i can change the color , text but i cant not change its frame very strange

Comment: Did you try turning off Use Autolayout?

Comment: hey guys i found another thing , if i am reloading the table it works fine....?

Comment: also by scrolling the Tableview it creates the cell on that size, means if new cell is created that is created from that value?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new label entirely and just directly setting cell.noteDesc = <new label>?

Comment: I think i have to change some thing if (cell == nil){
    NSLog(@"New Cell Made");

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NarrativeCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NarrativeCell class]])
        {
            cell = (NarrativeCell *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
} here

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20713/discussion-between-ali-and-stakenborg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cell is smaller than it's needed by text. So you need to find right cell height using the method heightForRowAtIndexpath. In case if you have enough space inside the cell for this resizing you should show us your XIB subviews hierarchy, seems like you doing something wrong (some superview clips to bounds your label).

P.S. Anyway it's not because you are using interface builder.